# Windows GPO order - beginner

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

I have some software that requires a .NET 4 install before them. I wonder what is the best way to make a GPO order list. I also have some software that needs certain files, so I need to prepare them first, (via batch file).

I have done some quick research however I haven't found the answer.

For example:

1. batch file cleans some folder
2. install .NET Framework 4
3. install apps through MSI (commercial software)

I can't pack everything in the MSI and I also need to make sure that all the steps succeed.

Comment: How about expanding on your question. Are you saying that you want to deploy an application with GPO but that the application has dependencies that you need to install first and that you want to install these dependencies with GPO and that you need to know the order in which GPO's are processed so that you can make sure the dependencies are installed before the application?

Comment: Hi joeqwerty, Could you explain a little bit so I could read around a bit? I can see that this can be two separate question however I need to deal with them in one:) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me suggest that what you want is a script.  A script that (as in your example) will perform some file/folder process, check to see that they've been performed, then call the .NET 4 framework installer, check that it installed, then call your `.msi`, and check that it's installed.

You won't be able to create something that aborts future steps if an earlier step fails by relying on GPO order/precedence.

Having said that, "what order do my GPOs apply in" is a common enough stumbling block or question that it deserves answered, so... [see `Application of Group Policy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736313%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

The big takeaway is:

> If you link more than one GPO to an Active Directory container, the GPO processing order (priority) is as follows: the GPO highest in the Group Policy Object Links list, displayed in the Group Policy page of the Active Directory container’s Properties page, has precedence by default. If you set the No Override option in one or more of the GPOs, the highest GPO that is set to No Override takes precedence.

Oh, but that's only if you have a very simple domain and OU structure.  See [`Order of processing settings`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778890%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and [`Group Policy processing and precedence`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785665%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) if you've got a more complicated setup.

Yeah, things get unsimple and unshort pretty fast with GPOs.  And domains.

Comment: thanks very much I am learning so I will get back as I can check this out on the system. Really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to install and deploy OS+softwares in the new machines you can use [IMAGEX - ***(please read this article)***](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command and modify [WIM images - ***(this article)***](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc507842.aspx) and use [SCCM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee390831.aspx#deploying_in_a_test_environment) and edit unattend file , SIM  you can use task sequence and define steps and requirement for install perquisites before other .msi files need dot net

1- Deploy the image using the task sequence

2- use necessary post-install scripts (that were specified in the original unattend file)

3- before that read : [System Requirements for .Net Framework 4](http://www.mypchealth.co.uk/Win7DeployFramework.php)

Comment: thanks very much I am learning so I will get back as I can check this out on the system. Really appreciate your answer

Comment: so if answer is use full please plus 1 that. thanks